# How to create banner in header

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

my site is on WP and I using Hueman theme. 
I want to add baner in right side of header. Now Im using header image, which have max. width and I dont know if I should add my banner on this header image or cut width header image and add banner next to it.

I searched a lot and I found a solution:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ads-11?replies=6#post-4906945

I have no idea where I can put divs with my banner, this is how looks header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <header id="header">
        <?php if ( has_nav_menu('topbar') ): ?>
            <nav class="nav-container group" id="nav-topbar">
                <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
                <div class="nav-text"><!-- put your mobile menu text here --></div>
                <div class="nav-wrap container"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'topbar','menu_class'=>'nav container-inner group','container'=>'','menu_id' => '','fallback_cb'=> false)); ?></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="container-inner">       
                        <div class="toggle-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                        <div class="search-expand">
                            <div class="search-expand-inner">
                                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/.container-inner-->
                </div><!--/.container-->
            </nav><!--/#nav-topbar-->
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="container group">
            <div class="container-inner">
                <?php if (ot_get_option('header-image') == ''): ?>
                <div class="group pad">
                    <?php echo alx_site_title(); ?>
                    <?php if (ot_get_option('site-description') != 'off'): ?><p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (ot_get_option('header-image')): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" rel="home">
                        <img class="site-image" src="<?php echo ot_get_option('header-image'); ?>" alt="<?php get_bloginfo('name'); ?>">
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (has_nav_menu('header')): ?>
                    <nav class="nav-container group" id="nav-header">
                        <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
                        <div class="nav-text"><!-- put your mobile menu text here --></div>
                        <div class="nav-wrap container"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'header','menu_class'=>'nav container-inner group','container'=>'','menu_id' => '','fallback_cb'=> false)); ?></div>
                    </nav><!--/#nav-header-->
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!--/.container-inner-->
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </header><!--/#header-->
    <div class="container" id="page">
        <div class="container-inner">           
            <div class="main">
                <div class="main-inner group">
```

And this is  my custom.css edited by me to hide this banner from mobile users

```
/* 
Add your custom styles in this file instead of style.css so it 
is easier to update the theme. Simply copy an existing style 
from style.css to this file, and modify it to your liking. 

When you update your theme, backup this file and re-add it after.
*/

/* Global */
.mystyle {}

.ads-header-desktop {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: -95px;
}

/* hide or display */
.ads-header-desktop { display: block; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.ads-header-desktop { display: none; }
}

/* Tablet - 800px, 768px & 720px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .mystyle {}
}


/* Mobile - 480px & 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 719px) {
    .mystyle {}
}


/* Mobile - 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .mystyle {}
}
```

Summa summarum:

This is my site: www.st-mobilny.pl and I want to do something like that: 1drv.ms/1RoUkIV

Comment: what is your site url ?

Comment: Does the banner need to be clickable? If not, you could just add the banner to the header graphic, as in Photoshop.

Comment: @coopersita yes i want clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to add it with position absolute:

```
<div class="container-inner">
            <div class="banner"><a href=""><img src="path/to/image" alt=""></a></div>
            <?php if (ot_get_option('header-image') == ''): ?>
```

In your CSS:

```
.container-inner {
      position: relative;
 }
.banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { .banner { position: static;} }
```

Change the `top` and `right` to whatever you want. I added a sample media query to show how you could change it, so once you go into mobile, the banner goes above the logo. If you want the banner below the logo, move the `div` in the html to above the menu.